# Convert from UTC string to device time - when device time is adjusted

Tags: android, datetime

I developed chat application, and the messages time are being saved in the server in UTC.

For ex. '2016-05-04T07:44:22.214419Z'.

I want to convert this time to the device time & date.

I know this way:

```
String dbDate = "2016-05-04T07:44:22.214419Z";

SimpleDateFormat mDBDateFormatZ = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
mDBDateFormatZ.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

GregorianCalendar deviceTime = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
deviceTime.setTime(mDBDateFormatZ.parse(dbDate));
```

This works perfectly when the device time is correct.

But when I set the android time manually, lets say we'll making it 10 minutes later. (there are those people who likes to see the time a bit later so they will have 10 minutes extra :)) The result of the code above is still the same.. It is only changing the hours. and not considering the time i adjusted.
also when i'm changing the date or the hours manually.

Is there a way to solve it ?

Comment: You need to get NTPUDPClient in commons-net library to get the actual time. Let me know if you need help and I can write you a little code

Comment: Don't know this `NTPUDPClient` library but what you suggest is to get the time from some server and compare it to the device time and add the differences in addition to the time zones ?

Comment: Yes. Thats right. I dont think there is any other way to do it.